# How to configure Neoformat to use Prettier?

Tags: neovim, formatting, plugin

Installed Neoformat with Plug in init.vim for Neovim 0.7.2 on Linux Mint 19.3

I can't figure out how to get Neoformat to work with Prettier.

I installed Prettier as a snap package in `--devmode`, so that it wouldn't be sandboxed.

I installed node package Prettier globally, and it does show up when I list the global packages with `npm list -g`.

I can use Prettier successfully on the command line.

But in nvim, `:Neoformat prettier` returns: `formatter definition for prettier not found.`

What critical step am I missing?
Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Installing prettier globally is not recommended by the devs.

And at the end of the [Config](https://github.com/sbdchd/neoformat#config-optional) there is an option to enable local prettier installation usage.

```
let g:neoformat_try_node_exe = 1
```

To use the globally installed `prettier`, add the installation directory to the path.

To find the installation path run

```
npm list -g
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'll check it out.